# Cannot upload images using CKEditor on message template after 5.45 upgrade

Tags: error, message-templates, images, upload

It was all working fine prior to upgrade. Now I am stuck and cannot upload images using message template CK Editor. Keep receiving this message when dragging picture on the window and getting an error message when using upload function. All other uploading throughout civicrm seems to works fine. Anyone had similar issues? How did you fix it please? Thanks

[image]

> Error message
>
> Error: Class 'kcfinder\CRM_Core_Config' not found in
> kcfinder\uploader->__construct() (line 118 of
> /home/webadmin/public_html/cmm-uat/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/core/class/uploader.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revert the [session id fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/commit/0bb407782b810c32a81e0ad42af67a435b44c845) until core team has a fix

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Can you check https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/pull/338 ?

Comment: This PR fixes the issue @Demerit . Thanks